# the code below tells me advance column is null what could be the error

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```
$stmt = $d->prepare("select loan_ball, amt_paid_wkly, sum(total_loan_bal) from loan_main t1 join collection t2 on 
    t1.loan_id = t2.loan_id where t1.loan_id = :loan_id");  // check for loan balance and amount to be paid weekly
    for($a=0;$a<count($loan_id);$a++) {  /*main for loop open here */ 
            $stmt->bindparam(':loan_id', $loan_id[$a],PDO::PARAM_INT);          
            $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){  // we generate the loan balance and weekly payment   /*secondary while loop*/
                $loan_ball_main_gen[$a] = $row['loan_ball']; // loan ballance generated from the loan_main table 
                $amt_paid_wkly_gen[$a] = $row['amt_paid_wkly']; // amount to be paid weekly from the database 
                $loan_ball_coll_gen[$a] = $row['sum(total_loan_bal)'];  // loan ballance generated from the collection table 
         }   
         if($amt_paid[$a] > $loan_ball_main_gen[$a]){  // if amount given is greater than loan balance we echo  and exit                                  
                     echo "boss " .$amt_paid[$a]. " is greater than the loan balance of " .$loan_ball_main_gen[$a];
                     exit();     
              }   
            if($loan_ball_coll_gen[$a] == 0){
            $loan_ba[$a] = $loan_ball_main_gen[$a] - $amt_paid[$a]; // the new loan balance we need to store in the main_loan and collection
            $amt[$a] = $amt_paid[$a] - $amt_paid_wkly_gen[$a]; // EQUATION TO DETERMINE ADVANCE AND OVERDUE //
            if($amt[$a] < 0){ // if amt is less than zero then we have overdue "so we multiply by -1 to make the value positive"
            $overdue[$a] = (-1 * $amt[$a]);
            $advance[$a] = 0;
            $total_advance[$a] = 0;
            $total_overdue[$a] = (-1 * $amt[$a]);
            } elseif($amt[$a] > 0){   // if amt is graeter than 0 we have an advance
            $advance[$a] = ($amt[$a] * 1);
            $overdue[$a] = 0;
            $total_overdue[$a] = 0;
            $total_advance[$a] = ($amt[$a] * 1);
            } elseif($amt[$a] == 0){   // if amt is 0 we have the exact value we needed 
            $advance[$a] = 0;
            $overdue[$a] = 0;
            $total_overdue[$a] = 0;
            $total_advance[$a] = 0;
             }      
            // echo $advance[$a]."<br/>"; 
             /**********/            
            $stmt = $d->prepare("update collection set amt_paid =:amt_paid,advance=:advance,total_advance=:total_advance,overdue =:overdue,
            total_overdue =:total_overdue,total_loan_bal =:total_loan_bal,date_coll=:date_coll, who_cre=:who_cre where coll_id=:coll_id");
            for($b=0;$b<count($coll_id);$b++) {
            $stmt->bindparam(':amt_paid',$amt_paid[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->bindparam(':advance',$advance[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT);  
            $stmt->bindparam(':total_advance',$total_advance[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->bindparam(':overdue',$overdue[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT); 
            $stmt->bindparam(':total_overdue',$total_overdue[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->bindparam(':total_loan_bal',$loan_ba[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindparam(':date_coll',$date_coll[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->bindparam(':who_cre',$who_cre[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindparam(':coll_id',$coll_id[$b],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $who_cre[$b] = 123; $date_coll[$b] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt == true){
            echo "saved successfully";
            }
                 }
             }  
            /**********/             
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing `$stmt->bindparam(':advance', ...)`?

Comment: $stmt->bindparam('advance ',......)  is already there

Comment: anyway the above code is lie lie this in summary   a for loop has another for loop inside it so the for loop inside uses results compared from an if statement to save information . but that loop inside fails to get the values from the if statement    i really need help because this issue has given me sleepless nights for some good weeks